# How to bind a value from a dynamically generated object to a DynamicComponent?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have an object whose type is generated at runtime. I also have a `DynamicComponent` which is a custom component with a parameter called `Value` with which I want to bind a property from the generated object. If I knew the types before runtime I would use `@bind-Value`, or `Value="@MyObject.Value"` and `ValueChanged="@(v => MyObject.Value = v)"`.

Here is my experimental code:

```
@foreach (FormInput input in form.Inputs)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type="@input.InputType" Parameters="@input.Parameters" />
}
```

```
@code
{
    private Form form;

    private string inputName = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InputAttribute reqAttribute = new()
        {
            Type = typeof(RequiredAttribute),
            ConstructorArguments = Array.Empty<object>()
        };

        FormInput input = new()
        {
            InputType = typeof(TsInputText),
            ReturnType = typeof(string),
            Attributes = new() { reqAttribute }
        };
        inputName = input.Id;

        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new();
        parameters.Add("Label", "Test");
        parameters.Add("PropertyName", input.Id);

        input.Parameters = parameters;

        List<FormInput> inputs = new() { input };

        form = new(inputs);

        form.BindProperty(input, "Value");
    }
}
```

Form class:

```
public Type Model { get; private set; }

public object Instance { get; private set; }

public List<FormInput> Inputs { get; set; }

public Form(IEnumerable<FormInput> inputs)
{
    // Model is generated here. 
    // Model has a property named input.Id for each input in the inputs argument.
    
    // Instance of the Model type is instantiated here
}

public void BindProperty(FormInput input, string inputParameter)
{
    input.Parameters.Add(inputParameter, GetPropertyInfo(Model, input.Id).GetValue(Instance));
    
    EventCallback<string> onChangeEvent = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, s => SetProperty(input.Id, s));
    input.Parameters.Add($"{inputParameter}Changed", onChangeEvent);
}
```

The `DynamicComponent`'s `Value` is initially set correctly, and `onChangeEvent` fires successfully when it is changed by the component, but externally setting the `form`'s `Value` does not subsequently update the component. I suspect that it's because `GetValue(Instance)` is returning a copy of `Value`. Is there a way to do this through references or will I have to manually update the `DynamicComponent`'s `Value` every time a `form` property is altered?

Comment: Are you trying to build a dynamic edit form?  You pass in a model and your builder produces an edit form with everything linked up?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes exactly

Comment: You can't use `DynamicComponent` it's just too generic and can't handling the binding and more complex parameter settings properly.  You will need to write your own Dynamic Component with lots of switch statements and all sorts of other logic to handle type convertions and different formatting options of controls.  Many have attempted this, good luck.  You'll find some simple examples out there on the internet.  And references to lots of questions on the subject on here.